# ¿Cómo ajustar el tamaño de un icono de una web usando html?

Tags: html

Gracias a todos por vuestro interés. Edito la pregunta a ver si ahora se entiende mejor:

Si se meten en esta página https://urbexa.com/page/test verán que abajo dice "Like us on Facebook - Follow us at Twitter" etc. y que justo arriba de esto hay un logo enorme de Facebook (una "f"). Lo que quiero es corregir el código de esa página para que el logo de Facebook remplace a la frase 'Like us on Facebook', y quiero que ese logo de Facebook aparezca con un tamaño adecuado (no como está ahora que es enorme).
En resumen, quiero que me quede como lo puso @Juan A. Ripoll Armengol en su respuesta de más abajo, pero sin tener que modificar ni agregar nada fuera de la propia página.

También me gustaría saber si en vez de usar el logo en base64 que hay ahora, se puede usar un icono de fontawesome sin tener que modificar ni tocar nada más de la web, pero de momento me conformo con poder solucionar la primera parte de mi pregunta. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido. A la pregunta le falta información sobre lo que has buscado/intentado, por otro lado mencionas "el código que puse antes" ¿A qué te refieres con ello?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida Rubén! Con lo de "el código que puse antes" me refería a este: http://imgur.com/2ME8KA9 que quise ponerlo en el mensaje pero no me dejaba porque era muy largo. Voy a reeditar mi pregunta a ver si queda más clara. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establece unas dimensiones a la imagen. Puedes añadir la siguiente clase a tu .css principal.

```
.parent-div img {
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Juan! Es justo eso lo que quiero conseguir, pero sin tener que tocar nada que esté fuera de esa página (como ves no entiendo mucho de esto pero creo que la .css es un archivo aparte, ¿no?). Lo que quiero es que me quede como te ha quedado a ti pero modificando solamente el código* que hay ahora, ¿es posible?

Comment: * Este es el código que hay ahora:

http://imgur.com/2ME8KA9

Comment: Añade esto en la etiqueta <img style='width: 24px; height: 24px;' alt...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!